# Why does not this SQL server INSERT query execute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I work on an ASP.NET project (using [serenity.is](http://serenity.is/)) and have now a problem with a database query :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("SimonTest/{id=0}/{obj=0}")]
public ActionResult SimonTest(int id, int obj)
{
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDb)\MSSqlLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=Serene5_Default_v1");

    // skipped code building the following command :

    command = "INSERT INTO [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[Errors] (TimeStp,IdSource,IdDestination,PortSource,PortDestination,ToTheRight,ToTheLeft) VALUES ('11:2','11','1','1','1',1,1);";


    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(command);
    SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(listDb, myConn);


    myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Commande exécutée");
    myCommand2.Dispose();


    myConn.Close();
    return View("~/Modules/Default/TcpDump/TcpDumpIndex.cshtml");
}
```

When I execute the query `INSERT INTO ...` with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, nothing goes wrong, but here the command seems to be skipped (no exception raised and nothing written in database)

Comment: And where exactly do you assign the SQL to execute to your command object? What is `listDb`? Did you mean to use `command` when constructing the `SqlCommand` object?

Comment: `command` != `listDb`. No idea what the contents of the latter is, but that's what you're executing.

Comment: Ok damn.. Was right at the beginning, and i wrote a new command and forgot to make every changes x)

Comment: I would like to point out that the "skipped code" that builds the SQL seems to insert values into it as well, you should use parameters, not concatenated SQL statements, depending on where you get these values from you might open yourself to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I will keep that in mind, thanks ! But what's the difference ? Why is the concatenation weaker x) ?

Comment: If you pick the values from textboxes on the screen then I can write this: `'; drop database x; select 1, '` this will then be concatenated into your SQL and bye bye database. Most likely won't this particular query execute but with some experimentation I should be able to either retrieve data you don't want me to or modify it. This bug is called SQL Injection - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assign sql text to command  `myCommand2.CommandText = command` before executing query.

Comment: He does in fact assign a SQL to the command, the constructor, `listDb` is that SQL, but it is the wrong SQL (most likely).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen maybe assignment of command text to the `listDb` is missing. And also it throws an exception when sql is wrong

Answer (score 0):

may be because of connection is not open that why it's not updating

```
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(listDb, myConn.Open());
```

Comment: Good point, I deleted it in the post, but actually opened it in my code ^^